# Find missing values in a sequence (sql)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table1

```
Empid    number
----------------
100         1
100         2
100         4
100         5
100         6
101         1
```

I'm self learning SQL, and a task I've come across is finding the missing values in sequence up to 12 and out putting which empid is associated.

I've attempted an approach that takes the above table and starts like

```
SELECT a number +1 , Min("through), MIn(by number) - 1
```

The entire approach use the existing numbers to find the missing "next/previous number. I'm able to output which numbers are missing. However I do not know how to group it with the associated id.

I also feel like I've complicated the task, I'm looking for guidance from anyone who can help on the best / most efficient way of going about this

Comment: create a numbers table 1-12.  cross join it to a distinct list of empID's then left join that to your table1. where table1.number is null.

Comment: what is the sequence where you have missing numbers?

Comment: The sequence is in the number table, 1,2,3,5,6 for example will show that 4 has been skipped

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all `empid`s and `numbers` are in the table somewhere, you can do this with a `cross join` and filter.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
select e.empid, n.number
from (select distinct empid from t) as e,
     (select distinct number from t) as n
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.empid = e.empid and t.number = n.number
                 );
```

This will not quite work for the data you have supplied.  To handle that situation, you need a table that has the 12 numbers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes you create a numbers table having Number column with 12 records value 1 to 12.

```
SELECT N.*, E.*
FROM NUMBERS N
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Distinct EmpID FROM table1) E
LEFT JOIN table1 T
  on T.EmpID = E.EmpID
 and T.Number = N.Number
WHERE T.EmpID is null
```

or substitute a derrived table for numbers table above

something like

```
(Select 1 as Number UNION ALL
Select 2 as Number UNION ALL
Select 3 as Number UNION ALL
Select 4 as Number UNION ALL
Select 5 as Number UNION ALL
Select 6 as Number UNION ALL
Select 7 as Number UNION ALL
Select 8 as Number UNION ALL
Select 9 as Number UNION ALL
Select 10 as Number UNION ALL
Select 11 as Number UNION ALL
Select 112 as Number)
```

I cant remember if MS Access will let you do this though...

Comment: You can do some trickery in MS Access to create a more flexible derived table: `SELECT DISTINCT Abs(Ones.ID Mod 10)+Abs(Tens.ID Mod 10)*10 AS Sequence
FROM MSysObjects AS Ones, MSysObjects AS Tens
WHERE Abs(Ones.ID Mod 10)+Abs(Tens.ID Mod 10)*10  BETWEEN 1 AND 12` generates a sequence from 0 to 99, and the `WHERE` filters out the ones you don't want. `MSysObjects` always contains enough IDs to make this work, even in an empty database.